# htaccess redirect to subdomain

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, robots.txt

I have a domain (say `example.com`). There is a folder in root named `freesites`. For each subfolder of `freesites` (say sf) I add a subdomain (`sf.example.com`). In each subfolder there is a separate web application started with `index.php` file.

```
root (example.com)
|-- index.php
|-- .htaccess
|-- ...
|-- freesites
  |-- sf1 (sf1.example.com)
    |-- index.php
    |-- ...
  |-- sf2 (sf2.example.com)
    |-- index.php
    |-- ...
  |-- sf3 (sf3.example.com)
    |-- index.php
    |-- ...
```

**The problem**: I don't want visitors to send requests as `example.com/freesites/sf1/blabla`. it doesn't work. I wish to redirect these requests to `sf1.example.com/blabla`. Furthermore I like to ban crawlers to do this type of requests.
What code I need in .htaccess and robots.txt?
**Note**: I redirected www to non-www in .htaccess now.

**Edit1**: `.htaccess` content is

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
IndexIgnore */*
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^freesites/([^/]+)/(.*)$ http://$1.example.com/$2 [R,L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.example.com
RewriteRule (.*) http://example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . index.php
```

and it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

As always, see [the documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html) if something is unclear in what I use in the (untested) code below:

```
RewriteRule ^freesites/([^/]+)/(.*)$ http://$1.example.com/$2 [R,L]
```

Crawlers -might- crawl these urls if they are linked from somewhere, but they too should follow the redirect and only save the 'good' url.

Comment: It doesn't work! I edited my question with `.htaccess` content.

Comment: Hmmm; I've quickly put this in my localhost and the rule is valid. I have no server with subdomains to test this on, so I can't help you much with that.