# Redirecting API requests to subdomain htaccess

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess

I'm aware there's a bunch of questions for this already, but no solution has worked.

I'm working with a Wordpress installation, the editor is making requests to `https://example.com/wp-json/wp/v2` expecting to find a Rest API there. However the Rest API is located at `https://api.example.com/wp-json/wp/v2`.

How to I redirect any API request to `https://example.com/wp-json/wp/v2/*` to `https://api.example.com/wp-json/wp/v2/*`?

Questions I've tried:

1. [One](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19746851/htaccess-redirect-to-subdomain)
2. [Two](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9334171/htaccess-redirect-to-subdomain)
3. [This generator](http://www.visiospark.com/mod-rewrite-rule-generator/)

EDIT:

What I've tried:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /wp-json/(\S*)\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://api.example.com/%1 [L,R=302]
```

```
RewriteRule ^example\.com$ /api.example.com?&%{QUERY_STRING}
```

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase / 

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^api\.example\.com$ [NC] 
RewriteRule ^wp-json/$ http://api.example.com [L,NC,R=301]
```

Already existing `.htaccess`:

```
  <IfModule mod_headers.c>
    <FilesMatch "\.(bmp|cur|gif|ico|jpe?g|png|svgz?|webp)$">
      Header Set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
      Header set Cache-Control "max-age=3024000, public"
    </FilesMatch>
  </IfModule>

# BEGIN WordPress

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} ^(.*)
RewriteRule ^(.*) - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%1]

RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress

<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
        AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/json
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Please don’t just go “Questions I've tried: …” All the info relevant to your problem, should be contained within your question itself - including what you tried. Plus, some of those questions have _multiple_ answers, and we don’t know what exactly you modified to fit your specific use case either - so that kind of statement is even more ambiguous and not helpful.

Comment: That being said, rather than trying to redirect, I would check if you can not manipulate those URLs using the `rest_url` filter.

Comment: I should've specified I've tried every answer to those questions. I added the rules to the OP, sorry about that. Will try the rest_url filter.

Comment: A redirect with status code 301/302 is a bad idea anyway, because that way you would lose all potential POST data, when the browser follows the redirect by making a GET request for the new URL. If anything, this would need to use 307/308. And even then, you would make the client send the whole request a second time, so for any larger POST requests that isn’t exactly good in terms of performance & traffic in first place.

Comment: That's fair. I've tried messing with `rest_url` but there's not a lot of info available. It also seems like it's used to identify specific requests to a certain id, not to change the rest_url.

Comment: It gets applied at the end of `get_rest_url`, and I would assume that WP is using that function internally as well, to determine the URLs for such endpoints. https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_rest_url/

Comment: @04FS Managed to get it to work, unfortunately that also breaks something in the actual Rest API which breaks my front-end. Is there really no way to do this easily with redirects?

Comment: Try modifying the last line of the third attempt you have shown above as follows: `RewriteRule ^(wp-json/.*)$ http://api.example.com/$1 [L,NC,R=307] ` In your current version, the pattern did not match to begin with, and you neglected to append the path to the target URL. And status code 307/308, to handle POST requests correctly as well.

Comment: That didn't work unfortunately

Comment: Where in the already existing .htaccess did you place this?

Comment: And please don’t go “didn’t work”, but be specific instead. Did it not redirect, did it redirect but broke the functionality, are you getting any errors, …

Comment: I placed it right after `<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>` as well as after the already existing `RewriteBase /`. It didn't do anything, no redirect, no errors. Errors in the editor are still shown as pointing to `example.com`.

Comment: According to https://htaccess.madewithlove.be, the rule itself should work. If it doesn’t for you in your setup, then you need to go and start looking into this a little deeper; debugging stuff like this “from the outside” isn’t that easy. Enabling rewrite logging can help in figuring out what is actually going on.

Comment: I might take a step back and look why changing the `rest_url` is breaking everything. Thank you for your help, I thought it was gonna be a bit easier than this but I was obviously wrong! Sorry for wasting your time

Comment: Hey, no worries, it’s not wasted time, when we discuss possible solutions to a problem. Just with the rewriting stuff, it can be really hard to debug, if one’s not sitting in front of the whole thing oneself.